# Locally free sheaf

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ a sheaf of rings over $X$. Let $F$ be a sheaf of $A$-modules over $X$.

The original motivation for my question is that I want to prove that locally free sheaves are torsion-free. For that matter I am arguing by contradiction, assuming that we have some section $s\in F(U)$ and some element $a\in A(U)$ such that $a \cdot s = 0$ in $F(U)$. I want to use that $F$ is locally free and partition $U$ with $U\cap U_\alpha$ where $\{U_\alpha\}$ is an open covering of $X$ such that
$$
F(U_\alpha) \simeq A(U_\alpha)^r
$$
for some constant $r$ (assuming $X$ is connected). However, I cannot close the following diagram from below
$\require{AMScd}$

\begin{CD}
F(U_\alpha) @>{\sim}>> A(U_\alpha)^r\\
@V{\rho}VV @V{\rho}VV\\
F(U\cap U_\alpha)  @. A(U\cap U_\alpha)
\end{CD}
which would allow me to easily reach a contradiction.

Any ideas on how to prove this?

Comment: Perhaps you are misunderstanding the definition of a locally free sheaf.  There is locally an isomorphism of sheaves $F|_U\simeq A|_U^r$, not just an isomorphism of modules $F(U)\simeq A(U)^r$.

Comment: Indeed I should have read the definition more carefully. Then I suppose that the module isomorphism "zooms in" as much as I want since it comes from a sheaf isomorphism?

Comment: Yes, you are right.